# HttpContext causing a bug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There is a bug in the system I am working on where every so often the users will "lose" the orders they are working on.

I have some code like this

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[OrderProductsSessionKey] != null)
{
     model  =(EditOrderProductsModel)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[OrderProductsSessionKey];
}
```

I don't see any issues in the logic getting to this area, debugging into the method looks ok and haven't been able to reproduce it yet. My question is, is it possible for these cookies to become corrupt? What would cause something like that and what could be done to prevent it?

Answer (score 5):

How are you storing that session? If you're using in-process storage (ASP.NET default) any application pool restart (recycle) will cause the session to be cleared.

IIS is configured by default to recycle the application pool every so often.

Switching to database or out of process session storage may help. Which of these is best for your application, depends on the type of application and the way it's deployed.

Comment: Addtionally, in proc sessions are only available to the server that the session was created on.  Many shared hosting providers use a cluster of servers (load balancing). If the request starts on one, it is not guaranteed to always return to that server, thus the session appears lost.  Same can happen with those that do not set a machine key on a shared hosting provider (user gets "logged out")